# Chrome Extension Fill in Selected Field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to build a very simple chrome extension that fills the selected form field on a page. I've created a git repo with the code:

https://github.com/mastermindg/chrome-extension-fillform

My problem is that nothing happens when I click the button.

Here's my background js:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
      d = document;

      var formfield = d.activeElement;
      d.getElementById(formfield).value = Math.floor(89+Math.random()*11);

});
```

I suspect it's around the js element selection process but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that perfect solution but the best I've seen so far...

I ended up using browser_action instead of background and using chrome.tabs.executeScript to affect the active tab. I updated my github repo as well with the current code.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
    {code:"var valued = Math.floor(89+Math.random()*11);var formfield = document.activeElement;formfield.value = valued"}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `d.getElementById(formfield).value` with just `formfield.value`.

`var formfield = d.activeElement;` gets the element for you, so `d.getElementById(formfield)` is not needed.

Comment: Chrome still fails to fill the form. I suspect that this is to because I'm deselecting the form when I"m clicking on the extension.